# Is it possible to fake destination directory path with zip?

Tags: zip

Given a bunch of files in the current directory, I want to be able to zip them such that, when extracted, they'd be placed in some given directories. For example, say I have these in `$PWD`:

```
ls
fsck
xz
chroot
```

And when I run `unzip foo.zip`, they each get extracted to these directories:

```
/bin
/sbin
/usr/bin
/usr/sbin
```

The closest I could find is that these files must already exist in whatever directory paths I want the files to be extracted to (using `$PWD` as root directory):

```
$ zip foo.zip bin/ls sbin/fsck usr/bin/xz usr/sbin/chroot
```

Then, on a system where I want this extraction to happen, I would have to:

```
$ cd /
$ sudo unzip foo.zip
```

Comment: it makes sense that a zip file can't contain absolute destination paths, otherwise this would be a security issue (i.e., uncompressing a zip file could maliciously replace system files). As a proof of concept, it could replace the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a way to do this using the `zip` command, but it's easy in python.

Note that the [zip file format specification](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT), section 4.4.17.1, says that the pathname cannot start with a '/', so I can't help with that part.

The python [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) module will let you override a file's pathname when you add it to the zip archive; just pass the desired name as the optional 2nd argument to `ZipFile.write`:

> ZipFile.write(filename[, arcname[, compress_type]])
>   Write the file named filename to the archive, giving it the archive name arcname (by default, this will be the same as filename, but without a drive letter and with leading path separators removed). If given, compress_type overrides the value given for the compression parameter to the constructor for the new entry.
>   Note: Archive names should be relative to the archive root, that is, they should not start with a path separator.

Here's an example:

```
$ touch 1 2 3
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
>>> import zipfile
>>> with zipfile.ZipFile('bundle.zip', 'w') as bundle:
...   bundle.write('1', '/bin/1')
...   bundle.write('2', '/sbin/2')
...   bundle.write('3', '/usr/bin/3')
... 
>>> 
$ unzip -l bundle
Archive:  bundle.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2014-08-11 13:00   bin/1
        0  2014-08-11 13:00   sbin/2
        0  2014-08-11 13:00   usr/bin/3
---------                     -------
        0                     3 files
```

Note that `zipfile.write` will remove any leading '/' from the pathname, to conform with the standard.

Comment: This still requires one to `cd` to `/` directory before extracting.

Comment: @Tshepang Yes, the [zip file format specification](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) says that the pathname cannot start with a '/'. If you give zipfile.write a pathname that starts with '/', it will be removed. I've edited my answer to add this.

Comment: to create such a zip wouldn't be sufficient to create the directory structure inside a temporary dir, hard linking the needed files, and then generate the zip file from there?

Comment: @pqnet I mentioned that approach in my Question.

Comment: @Tshepang sorry I misunderstood your words thinking that you would actually use the root directory. What I meant to say is that unless you are using python as packaging tool (so that you don't have to parse the lists) this solution is pretty much the same thing.